# ajax cache problems with view model

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching, model-view-controller, controller

I am using jquery and AJAX in mvc on a view also have custom HTML helpers. On the page is a drop down list, when I change the index, I call the AJAX method. The method checks the value of the drop down then accordingly hides form fields on the page. I go into debug mode and the conditional fires to hide the form fields but the page comes back with the form fields visible. In the AJAX call I set the cache property to false. Is their something else I should do to have the page not cache? DO I have to use the replace keyword to get rid of the cached fields? Thanks for any help.

Code I use:

**Ajax:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $("#NameCD").change(function(e) {
         $.ajaxSetup({
             cache: false
         });
         e.preventDefault();
         var strSelected = "";

         $("#NameCD option:selected").each(function() {
             strSelected += $(this)[0].value;
         });

         if (strSelected) {


             $.ajax({
                 type: "GET",
                 url: '@Url.Action("_NameInsert", "Name")' + '?nrn=' + strSelected,
                 data: {
                     nrn: strSelected
                 },
                 dataType: 'html',
                 cache: false,
                 async: true
             });

         }
     });
 });
```

view Custom **Html** **Helper**

```
 @Html.TextBoxForName(x => x.Salutation, ViewBag.NameCD as string, new { @class = "form-control col-md-3" })
```

**C# Code**

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxForName < TModel, TProperty > (this HtmlHelper < TModel > htmlHelper, Expression < Func < TModel, TProperty >> expression, object namecode, object htmlAttributes = null) {
    var attrs = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(NameSelect.NameCodeDisable), namecode.ToString().Trim())) {
        attrs.Add("style", "display:none;");
    }
    return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, attrs);
}
```

Comment: Unclear what your asking. You making an ajax call which stays on the same page. Unless you update the DOM in the success call back, there will be no change to the view.

Comment: I run debugger and the action on the controller is called it returns the view.  the helper extender is called and the conditional runs, and since the cache is set to false I thought the view would be updated withe the returned view. How would I update the DOM?

Comment: If the method your calling is returning a partial view, then your need `$.ajax({ .... success: function(data) { $(someElement).html(data); }`